# Google Analytics: Time on "Screen" for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

We want to track via Google Analytics the amount of time the user spends on each fragment of one activity.

Just to be clear, we have one activity and many fragments that belongs to the same activity.

I need to know how much time the user spent in each of those fragments and send it as "Time on screen". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this we should use Google Analytics *Manual Screen Measurement*

from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/screens

```
// May return null if EasyTracker has not yet been initialized with a property
// ID.
Tracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to null.
easyTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Home Screen");

easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
    .createAppView()
    .build()
);
```

Notice the comment: "*This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with hits until it is set to a new value or to null.*"

Comment: I don't you want to do EasyTracker.getInstance(this).  I think you want to do EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).  This is a fragment.